# Error in login event listener?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Spring Security for authentication. I am using login event listener to record the last logged in time of the users

in conf/spring/resources.groovy i have

```
loginEventListener(LoginEventListener)
```

and the listener is defined as

```
class LoginEventListener implements
    ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    //deal with successful login
    void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        User.withTransaction {

            def user = User.findById(event.authentication.principal.id)
            if(!user.isAttached())
                user.attach()
            user.lastLoginTime = new Date() // update login time
            user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)


        }


    }


}
```

The error i am getting is at this point

```
user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

the error is as follows

```
ERROR 2017-05-31 16:04:15,715 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-9659] events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [User#7]
    at LoginEventListener$_onApplicationEvent_closure1.doCall(LoginEventListener.groovy:18)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:686)
    at LoginEventListener.onApplicationEvent(LoginEventListener.groovy:12)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am trying to understand the cause of this error and how can i avoid it? Is flush:true the cause of the error? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: try `User.withNewTransaction { User user  = User.get(event.authentication.principal.id)` findById :)

Comment: thanks but i want to know the reason as well. do you know the cause of this error?

Comment: `Row was updated or deleted by another transaction` You possibly have another event transaction triggered that was looking up the record elsewhere and still hanging on to object and you attempt to remove it then fails. Doing a new transaction means you are getting a fresh instance.When you have withTransaction usually you don't need flush:true too - but using not using all has different effects depending on situation - so my answer isn't and answer its about tweaking something over and over and testing behaviour

Comment: - also DO RESTART app since I have noticed around deletion calls a restarting an application sometimes makes the same call that worked previously not work when running a clean instance. So always test your last working code on a fresh running app

Comment: ok thanks i will see if this solves the problem